# Difference between CustomTextView as Parent and Textview as Parent

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance, android-custom-view

i created CustomTextview as below

```
public class CustomTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
        public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       // im changing font family here .ttf files
    }
}
```

.

```
<com.android.app.CustomTextView
android:id="@+id/view”
/>
```

what is the difference between

This

```
CustomTextView textView = findViewbyId(R.id.view);
```

and this

```
TextView textView = findViewbyId(R.id.view);
```

When i put this `TextView textView = findViewbyId(R.id.view);` IDE runs without throwing error. Why? Thanks!

Comment: Your CustomTextView "is a" TextView via inheritance

Comment: Is there any difference in assigning the id to Parent or Child Class?

Comment: Presumably you've created the CustomTextView because you want to add some behaviour to TextView that it doesn't currently have? In that case you would want to declare it to be this type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A real life comparison:

> When you learn to drive a manual transmission car, you can drive
> almost any manual transmission car. Imagine how bad it would be if you
> had to learn to drive every different model of car you encounter.

Source [(+)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/314084)

Comment: Another example : Mercedes Benz inherits Car class. Benz is always a car and if you say i drive a car (instead of Mercedes Benz), your are not wrong at all, so this is normal that IDE runs without throwing error!